# ValueError when reading from a file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a python script that reads items from a file, devices.txt and then populates a dictionary. Now this file has the following structure:

```
uniqueId,RoomLabel,Label,State,Frequency
```

Eg:

```
1001,lounge,lamp,False,6789
```

Now when python reads that alone, it's fine. However, when I populate the file further:

```
1001,lounge,lamp,False,5169,1002,lounge,tv,False,6789
```

It spits out:

```
unId = int(value[0])
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

This is the code running at this point of the program:

```
with open("devices.txt") as file:
for line in file:
    value = line.rstrip('\n').split(",")
    unId = int(value[0])
    rmLabel = value[1]
    label = value[2]
    state = value[3]
    freq = int(value[4])
    irTable[unId] = rmLabel, label, state, freq
```

With that in mind, i'm failing to see where it's finding an int() with a base of 10, I'm awful at math, but as I understand, for it to be a base of 10 it would be seeing a decimal correct?

Comment: It's because your two items are on the same line.

Comment: Nope :/ I've dropped the second set down a line and it's still spitting out the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''` means the following:

You asked Python to convert an object to an integer by calling `int()`.

Because you didn't specify a base, it assumes a default of `10` (decimal) (you could for example tell it to parse a number in hex by specifying a base of `16`: `int('ff', 16)`). And the value that caused this exception was `''` (the empty string). So the empty string `''` cannot be converted to an integer using base 10 (or any other base in this case).

The exact line of code where this call to `int()` happened is printed just above the exception:

```
unId = int(value[0])
```

So you know that `value[0]` is equal to `''` at some point.

The reason for this is most likely that you either have empty fields or an empty line in your `*.csv` file. Print `line` and `value` to see whats going on.

This should help you to figure out the problem in your code and/or data, and how to read Python exceptions. But after you fixed this bug you should really use the built in [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) module to parse CSV files, like @Joran Beasley suggested.

Answer (score 0):

It's trying to convert the 0'th value on the comma-delimited line into an integer (using base 10, but the base is probably not relevant.) This error most likely means that the string that is actually at the 0'th position on the line is not a recognizable number (for example, your `devices.txt` may be improperly formatted somewhere such that a line starts with `lounge,lamp,False, ...` instead of a number, or that the id field is empty at some point (e.g. `,lounge,lamp,...`).

Answer (score 0):

The error message ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '' means the following:

You asked Python to convert an object to an integer by calling int().

One way you can fix this is by doing the following:
turn `value` into a string and then use the `replace()` method like this.

```
value = value.replace(' ', '')
```

Note: You can insert anything into the first set of `''`. This will replace it with whatever is in the second set of `''`. Be sure to leave the second set without any spaces or characters if you want it to be removed.

Do this for every single character that can not be turned into an integer. These include: !@#$%^&*()_+{}[]":;'?><,./|+=-

To find out which characters you have that might not be convertible to an integer do the following:

```
print(repr(value))
```

This will show all of your characters. Just use the replace method on any that you can not convert.

Hope this helps :)